# JavaFX-How to fix image load failure in a .jnlp file need serious @!d

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jnlp

Alright I have scoured the internet for day's trying to figure this problem out and I'm hoping someone here can help me, I wrote a simple TicTacToe game that has pane's inside a gridpane for the board. When you click on one of the pane's the Javafx program loads an image either x.jpg or o.jpg depending on who's turn it is. The program when ran from compiler works fine, when the .jar file is ran works fine....but when I run the .jnlp through the test .html file generated the panes register my mouse clicks but the images won't load...and if I try running it as stand alone It won't even register the mouse clicks it acts as though I didn't click anything...I even tried changing the path of the file to a uri and still the same problem. Like I said the .jar file runs fine just not the .jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="JavaFXApp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>TicTacToe</title>
    <vendor>John_Conner</vendor>
    <description>This is a simple Tic Tac Toe game</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="JavaFXApp.jar" size="39388" download="eager" />
  </resources>
  <applet-desc  width="300" height="400" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="TicTacToe" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="300" height="400" main-class="TicTacToe.TicTacToe1_2"  name="TicTacToe" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

To add to this, when I load the test html file and select "click to launch this app as webstart". I receive an Application Error which says "Unable to launch the application." and when I select details I get the message below

```
java.lang.Throwable: Launch file error
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.parseArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "UsersJohnIdeaProjectsTic_Tac_ToeoutartifactsTicTacToeJavaFXApp.html"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.HtmlOptions.importProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.HtmlOptions.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.HtmlOptions.create(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "UsersJohnIdeaProjectsTic_Tac_ToeoutartifactsTicTacToeJavaFXApp.html"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.Handler.parseURL(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
```

My best guess is that perhaps it has something to do with the way it looks for the image files but as I said I am fairly new to Java in general so I am unsure what all this means, other then perhaps a command within the .html may have caused it so I will paste that as well.

```
<html><head>
  <SCRIPT src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
    function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
        dtjava.launch(            {
                url : 'JavaFXApp.jnlp'
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
        return false;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function javafxEmbed_JavaFXApp_id() {
        dtjava.embed(
            {
                id : 'JavaFXApp_id',
                url : 'JavaFXApp.jnlp',
                placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
                width : 300,
                height : 400
            },
            {
                javafx : '2.2+'
            },
            {}
        );
    }
    <!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
    dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed_JavaFXApp_id);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>TicTacToe</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='JavaFXApp.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('JavaFXApp.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a><br><hr><br>

  <!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
  <div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

Just to make sure I didn't miss anything...Here is the source code

```
/**
 * Created by John on 7/27/2014.
 */
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/27/2014.
 */
public class TicTacToe1_2 extends Application {
    // Indicate which player has a turn, initially it is the X player
    private char whoseTurn = 'X';
    private Color fontFill = Color.LIME;
    private String player1name = "Player1";
    private int player1Score = 0;
    private String player2name = "Player2";
    private int player2Score = 0;

    // Create and initialize cell
    private Cell[][] cell = new Cell[3][1];

    // Create and initialize a status label
    private Label lblStatus = new Label("Start a New Game");

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Pane to hold cell
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);

        // Creates a welcome screen
        Pane welcomePane = new Pane();
        welcomePane.setPrefSize(315, 407);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 30);
        Text txWelcome = new Text("Start A New Game!");
        txWelcome.setFont(font);
        txWelcome.setFill(fontFill);
        txWelcome.setX(welcomePane.getPrefWidth() * 0.02);
        txWelcome.setY(welcomePane.getPrefHeight() / 2);
        welcomePane.getChildren().add(txWelcome);

        // Menu for starting and resetting a game
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu fileMenuButton = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem miNew = new MenuItem("New");
        MenuItem miScores = new MenuItem("Scores");
        fileMenuButton.getItems().addAll(miNew, miScores);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenuButton);

        // BorderPane to hold the cells and label and menu
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        lblStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: lime");
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
        borderPane.setCenter(welcomePane);

        // Have the New menu item start a new game
        miNew.setOnAction(e -> {
            setPlayerNames().show();
            whoseTurn = 'X';
            borderPane.getChildren().removeAll(pane, lblStatus);
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
            borderPane.setCenter(pane);
            lblStatus = new Label("X's turn to play");
            lblStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: lime");
            borderPane.setBottom(lblStatus);
        });

        // Have the Scores menu item show the scores
        miScores.setOnAction(e -> {
            showScores().show();
        });

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TicTacToe"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /** Start */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /** Opens a window to enter the player names */
    public Stage setPlayerNames() {
        // Create a window for entering the player1's names
        Stage player1 = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        player1.centerOnScreen();
        HBox play1NameHBox = new HBox(20);
        play1NameHBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Label lbPlayer1 = new Label("Enter Player1's name: ");
        lbPlayer1.setTextFill(fontFill);
        TextField tfPlayer1 = new TextField(player1name);
        tfPlayer1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                "-fx-text-fill: lime; -fx-border-color: lime");
        tfPlayer1.setPrefWidth(100);
        play1NameHBox.getChildren().addAll(lbPlayer1, tfPlayer1);
        play1NameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene name1Scene = new Scene(play1NameHBox, 280, 40);
        player1.setTitle("Player1's Name");
        player1.setScene(name1Scene);

        // Create a window for entering the player2's names
        Stage player2 = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        player2.centerOnScreen();
        HBox play2NameHBox = new HBox(20);
        play2NameHBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Label lbPlayer2 = new Label("Enter Player2's name: ");
        lbPlayer2.setTextFill(fontFill);
        TextField tfPlayer2 = new TextField(player2name);
        tfPlayer2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                "-fx-text-fill: lime; -fx-border-color: lime");
        tfPlayer2.setPrefWidth(100);
        play2NameHBox.getChildren().addAll(lbPlayer2, tfPlayer2);
        play2NameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene name2Scene = new Scene(play2NameHBox, 280, 40);
        player2.setTitle("Player2's Name");
        player2.setScene(name2Scene);

        // Set the player names upon pressing enter
        tfPlayer1.setOnAction(e -> {
            player1name = tfPlayer1.getText();
            player1.close();
            player2.show();
        });

        tfPlayer2.setOnAction(e -> {
            player2name = tfPlayer2.getText();
            player2.close();
        });

        return player1;
    }

    /** Opens the scores window */
    public Stage showScores() {
        // Create a new window for displaying the history
        Stage playerScores = new Stage();
        playerScores.centerOnScreen();
        VBox players = new VBox(25);
        players.setSpacing(20);
        players.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        players.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox player1 = new HBox();
        player1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox player2 = new HBox();
        player2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 20);

        // Set Player1's name and score
        Text txPlayer1Name = new Text(this.player1name);
        txPlayer1Name.setFont(font);
        txPlayer1Name.setFill(fontFill);
        Text txPlayer1Score = new Text();
        txPlayer1Score.setFont(font);
        txPlayer1Score.setFill(fontFill);
        txPlayer1Score.setText(String.format(": %d", this.player1Score));
        player1.getChildren().addAll(txPlayer1Name, txPlayer1Score);

        // Set Player2's name and score
        Text txPlayer2Name = new Text(this.player2name);
        txPlayer2Name.setFont(font);
        txPlayer2Name.setFill(fontFill);
        Text txPlayer2Score = new Text();
        txPlayer2Score.setFont(font);
        txPlayer2Score.setFill(fontFill);
        txPlayer2Score.setText(String.format(": %d", this.player2Score));
        player2.getChildren().addAll(txPlayer2Name, txPlayer2Score);

        // Add to VBox
        players.getChildren().addAll(player1, player2);

        // Create a scene and add it too the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(players, 300, 75);
        playerScores.setTitle("Player Scores"); // Set the stage title
        playerScores.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage

        return playerScores;
    }

    /** Determine if the cells are all occupied */
    public boolean isFull() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if (cell[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

    /** Determine if the player with the specified token wins */
    public boolean isWon(char token) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (cell[i][0].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[i][2].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[i][3].getToken() == token) {
                return true;
            }

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (cell[0][j].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[1][j].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[2][j].getToken() == token)  {
                return true;
            }
        // Check diagonals
        if (cell[0][0].getToken() == token &&
                cell[1][4].getToken() == token &&
                cell[2][5].getToken() == token) {
            return true;
        } else if (cell[0][6].getToken() == token &&
                cell[1][7].getToken() == token &&
                cell[2][0].getToken() == token) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // An inner class for a cell
    public class Cell extends Pane {
        // Token used for this cell
        private char token = ' ';

        public Cell() {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                    "-fx-border-color: lime");
            this.setPrefSize(105, 125);
            this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleMouseClick());
        }

        /** Return token */
        public char getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        /** Set a new token */
        public void setToken(char c) {
            token = c;

            if (token == 'X') {
                ImageView imageX = new ImageView("/image/x.jpg");
                imageX.setX(this.getPrefWidth() * 0.035);
                imageX.setY(this.getPrefHeight() * 0.035);
                this.getChildren().add(imageX);
            } else if (token == 'O') {
                ImageView imageO = new ImageView("/image/o.jpg");
                imageO.setX(this.getPrefWidth() * 0.035);
                imageO.setY(this.getPrefHeight() * 0.035);
                this.getChildren().add(imageO);
            }
        }

        /* Handle a mouse click event */
        private void handleMouseClick() {
            // If cell is empty and game is not over
            if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ') {
                setToken(whoseTurn); // Set token in the cell

                // Check game status
                if (isWon(whoseTurn)) {
                    lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! The game is over");
                    if (whoseTurn == 'X') {
                        player1Score++;
                    } else {
                        player2Score++;
                    }
                    whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
                } else if (isFull()) {
                    lblStatus.setText("Draw! the game is over");
                    whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
                } else {
                    // Change the turn
                    whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
                    // Display whose turn
                    lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an image of the JavaFXApp.jar file in action
[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Someone please help, throw me a link or something...can't seem to find any good walkthrough's on this....going on day 2 and still can't figure it out

Comment: Correction it does in fact actually register the mouse clicks in the .jnlp when ran as standalone, just not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out!!! :) I finally figured it out, I actually want to thank everyone for not answering me over nearly a 24 hour period lol...Still not sure what the exact source of the problem was but I figure that it had something to do with the way it was trying to load the image obviously. Well if anyone has any alternative methods please let me know, but I got my .jnlp file fully functional...I had to create a buffered version of the image which I retrieved using the TicTacToe1_2.class.getResourcesAsStream("/imagefolder/image.jpg"); Format

Below is the entire source code followed by a link to the site in which I found the solution

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/27/2014.
 */
public class TicTacToe1_2 extends Application {
    // Indicate which player has a turn, initially it is the X player
    private char whoseTurn = 'X';
    private Color fontFill = Color.LIME;
    private String player1name = "Player1";
    private int player1Score = 0;
    private String player2name = "Player2";
    private int player2Score = 0;

    // Create and initialize cell
    private Cell[][] cell = new Cell[3][3];

    // Create and initialize a status label
    private Label lblStatus = new Label("Start a New Game");

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Pane to hold cell
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);

        // Creates a welcome screen
        Pane welcomePane = new Pane();
        welcomePane.setPrefSize(315, 407);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 30);
        Text txWelcome = new Text("Start A New Game!");
        txWelcome.setFont(font);
        txWelcome.setFill(fontFill);
        txWelcome.setX(welcomePane.getPrefWidth() * 0.02);
        txWelcome.setY(welcomePane.getPrefHeight() / 2);
        welcomePane.getChildren().add(txWelcome);

        // Menu for starting and resetting a game
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu fileMenuButton = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem miNew = new MenuItem("New");
        MenuItem miScores = new MenuItem("Scores");
        fileMenuButton.getItems().addAll(miNew, miScores);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenuButton);

        // BorderPane to hold the cells and label and menu
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        lblStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: lime");
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
        borderPane.setCenter(welcomePane);

        // Have the New menu item start a new game
        miNew.setOnAction(e -> {
            setPlayerNames().show();
            whoseTurn = 'X';
            borderPane.getChildren().removeAll(pane, lblStatus);
            pane.getChildren().clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    pane.add(cell[i][j] = new Cell(), j, i);
            borderPane.setCenter(pane);
            lblStatus = new Label("X's turn to play");
            lblStatus.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: lime");
            borderPane.setBottom(lblStatus);
        });

        // Have the Scores menu item show the scores
        miScores.setOnAction(e -> {
            showScores().show();
        });

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TicTacToe"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /** Start */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    /** Opens a window to enter the player names */
    public Stage setPlayerNames() {
        // Create a window for entering the player1's names
        Stage player1 = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        player1.centerOnScreen();
        HBox play1NameHBox = new HBox(20);
        play1NameHBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Label lbPlayer1 = new Label("Enter Player1's name: ");
        lbPlayer1.setTextFill(fontFill);
        TextField tfPlayer1 = new TextField(player1name);
        tfPlayer1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                "-fx-text-fill: lime; -fx-border-color: lime");
        tfPlayer1.setPrefWidth(100);
        play1NameHBox.getChildren().addAll(lbPlayer1, tfPlayer1);
        play1NameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene name1Scene = new Scene(play1NameHBox, 280, 40);
        player1.setTitle("Player1's Name");
        player1.setScene(name1Scene);

        // Create a window for entering the player2's names
        Stage player2 = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
        player2.centerOnScreen();
        HBox play2NameHBox = new HBox(20);
        play2NameHBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        Label lbPlayer2 = new Label("Enter Player2's name: ");
        lbPlayer2.setTextFill(fontFill);
        TextField tfPlayer2 = new TextField(player2name);
        tfPlayer2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                "-fx-text-fill: lime; -fx-border-color: lime");
        tfPlayer2.setPrefWidth(100);
        play2NameHBox.getChildren().addAll(lbPlayer2, tfPlayer2);
        play2NameHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene name2Scene = new Scene(play2NameHBox, 280, 40);
        player2.setTitle("Player2's Name");
        player2.setScene(name2Scene);

        // Set the player names upon pressing enter
        tfPlayer1.setOnAction(e -> {
            player1name = tfPlayer1.getText();
            player1.close();
            player2.show();
        });

        tfPlayer2.setOnAction(e -> {
            player2name = tfPlayer2.getText();
            player2.close();
        });

        return player1;
    }

    /** Opens the scores window */
    public Stage showScores() {
        // Create a new window for displaying the history
        Stage playerScores = new Stage();
        playerScores.centerOnScreen();
        VBox players = new VBox(25);
        players.setSpacing(20);
        players.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        players.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox player1 = new HBox();
        player1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox player2 = new HBox();
        player2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 20);

        // Set Player1's name and score
        Text txPlayer1Name = new Text(this.player1name);
        txPlayer1Name.setFont(font);
        txPlayer1Name.setFill(fontFill);
        Text txPlayer1Score = new Text();
        txPlayer1Score.setFont(font);
        txPlayer1Score.setFill(fontFill);
        txPlayer1Score.setText(String.format(": %d", this.player1Score));
        player1.getChildren().addAll(txPlayer1Name, txPlayer1Score);

        // Set Player2's name and score
        Text txPlayer2Name = new Text(this.player2name);
        txPlayer2Name.setFont(font);
        txPlayer2Name.setFill(fontFill);
        Text txPlayer2Score = new Text();
        txPlayer2Score.setFont(font);
        txPlayer2Score.setFill(fontFill);
        txPlayer2Score.setText(String.format(": %d", this.player2Score));
        player2.getChildren().addAll(txPlayer2Name, txPlayer2Score);

        // Add to VBox
        players.getChildren().addAll(player1, player2);

        // Create a scene and add it too the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(players, 300, 75);
        playerScores.setTitle("Player Scores"); // Set the stage title
        playerScores.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage

        return playerScores;
    }

    /** Determine if the cells are all occupied */
    public boolean isFull() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                if (cell[i][j].getToken() == ' ')
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

    /** Determine if the player with the specified token wins */
    public boolean isWon(char token) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            if (cell[i][0].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[i][1].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[i][2].getToken() == token) {
                return true;
            }

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (cell[0][j].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[1][j].getToken() == token &&
                    cell[2][j].getToken() == token)  {
                return true;
            }
        // Check diagonals
        if (cell[0][0].getToken() == token &&
                cell[1][1].getToken() == token &&
                cell[2][2].getToken() == token) {
            return true;
        } else if (cell[0][2].getToken() == token &&
                cell[1][1].getToken() == token &&
                cell[2][0].getToken() == token) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // An inner class for a cell
    public class Cell extends Pane {
        // Load image variables
        String val;
        Image bufferedImage;

        // Token used for this cell
        private char token = ' ';

        public Cell() {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;" +
                    "-fx-border-color: lime");
            this.setPrefSize(105, 125);
            this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleMouseClick());
        }

        /** Return token */
        public char getToken() {
            return token;
        }

        /** Set a new token */
        public void setToken(char c) {
            token = c;

            if (token == 'X') {
                val = "x.jpg";
                // Use SwingFXUtils.toFXImage() to convert the image from a Swing to JavaFX
                bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(
                        LoadImage("image/" + val), null);
                // final String image = "file:///C:/image/x.jpg";
                ImageView imageX = new ImageView(bufferedImage);
                imageX.setX(this.getPrefWidth() * 0.035);
                imageX.setY(this.getPrefHeight() * 0.035);
                this.getChildren().add(imageX);
            } else if (token == 'O') {
                val = "o.jpg";
                // Use SwingFXUtils.toFXImage() to convert the image from a Swing to JavaFX
                bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage( 
                        LoadImage("image/" + val), null);
                // final String image = "file:///C:/image/o.jpg";
                ImageView imageO = new ImageView(bufferedImage);
                imageO.setX(this.getPrefWidth() * 0.035);
                imageO.setY(this.getPrefHeight() * 0.035);
                this.getChildren().add(imageO);
            }
        }

        /** Load an image and return a buffered image */
        public BufferedImage LoadImage(String f) {
            BufferedImage bi = null;
            try {
                // Load image into an InputStream from the jar file
                InputStream is = TicTacToe1_2.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + f);
                // Set the image to the BufferedImage variable
                bi = ImageIO.read(is);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                // Create a message and place it in a pane
                Label message = new Label("ERROR opening file:" + e);
                message.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                Pane pane = new Pane(message);
                // Create stage and scene and place scene in stage
                Stage errorMessage = new Stage();
                Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
                errorMessage.setTitle("Error!"); // Set the stage title
                errorMessage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
                errorMessage.show();
            }

            return bi;
        }

        /* Handle a mouse click event */
        private void handleMouseClick() {
            // If cell is empty and game is not over
            if (token == ' ' && whoseTurn != ' ') {
                setToken(whoseTurn); // Set token in the cell

                // Check game status
                if (isWon(whoseTurn)) {
                    lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + " won! The game is over");
                    if (whoseTurn == 'X') {
                        player1Score++;
                    } else {
                        player2Score++;
                    }
                    whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
                } else if (isFull()) {
                    lblStatus.setText("Draw! the game is over");
                    whoseTurn = ' '; // Game is over
                } else {
                    // Change the turn
                    whoseTurn = (whoseTurn == 'X') ? 'O' : 'X';
                    // Display whose turn
                    lblStatus.setText(whoseTurn + "'s turn");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](http://faculty.cs.wit.edu/~ldeligia/LinkDocs/howtoWEBSTART.html) is the link to the site in which I ended up finding the solution, the solution is at the very bottom of the page where it explains how to load images from within the jar.